# scala java.lang.ClassCastException during randomSplit

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

In the code below cohort_counts_4 is a dataframe that has 3 columns g,samplingRate and samplingRate1. In the rowDF variable I am collecting the columns samplingRate and samplingRate1 (which are percentages). And in the 
percentages variable I am converting it to `Array[Double]`.

When I am trying to run this, I am getting the error below during runtime in the percentages. I need it to be `Array[Double]` as I have to randomSplit in the next step.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Double.
```

Please let me know your thoughts.

sample data of percentages -

```
percentages: Array[Seq[Double]] =
 Array(WrappedArray(0.06449504858964898, 0.9355049514103511)
     , WrappedArray(0.015861918725594032, 0.9841380812744059)
     , WrappedArray(0.22082241578907924, 0.7791775842109208)
     , WrappedArray(0.14416119376185044, 0.8558388062381496)
     , WrappedArray(0.10958692395592619, 0.8904130760440738)
     , WrappedArray(1.0, 0.0)
     , WrappedArray(0.6531128743810083, 0.3468871256189917)
     , WrappedArray(0.04880653326943304, 0.9511934667305669))
```

```
val cohortList = cohort_counts_4.select("g").collect().map(_(0)).toList
var cohort_list = new ListBuffer[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]()
var total_rows: Int = 0
for (igroupid<-cohortList){
    val sample_rate = cohort_counts_4.filter(col("g")===igroupid).select("samplingRate","samplingRate1") 
   cohort_list += sample_rate
  val curr_rows = sample_rate.count().toInt
  total_rows += curr_rows
}
val customers_new = cohort_list.reduce(_ union _)
val rowDF = customers_new.select(array(customers_new.columns.map(col):_*) as "row")
var percentages =Array(rowDF.collect.map(_(0)).asInstanceOf[Double])
// var percentages = rowDF.collect.map(_.getSeq[Double](0))
val uni = customers_2.select("x","g").distinct
      .randomSplit(percentages)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code from

```
var percentages =Array(rowDF.collect.map(_(0)).asInstanceOf[Double])
```

to below

```
var percentages =rowDF.collect.map(_(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]]).flatten
```

and it worked.